# How to add values to a string array in android

Tags: android, json, for-loop, arrays

I have a problem with my code,

I have a json array

```
                [{"Response":{"data":"sibin1"}},{"Response":{"data":"sibin2"}},
                              {"Response": {"data":"sibin3"}}]
```

And iam trying to extract the json data using the below code,Here i added only some parts of the coode

```
                 JSONArray  finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
                 int finalresultlengt=finalResult.length();
                 JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject();
      for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length(); i++) 
            {

          json_data = finalResult.getJSONObject(i);
          System.out.println("json dataa"+json_data.names().toString());
          JSONObject menuObject = json_data.getJSONObject("Response");
          result=   menuObject.getString("data");   
             System.out.println(result);
              }
```

The code is worked very well

when the value of

```
                    i=0 ,result is sibin1
                    i=1 ,result is sibin2
                    i=2 ,result is sibin3
```

But my problem is , i need to store the result in a string array of length finalresultlength inside the given for loop, also i need to print the values in the string array in a for loop outside the given for loop
if anybody knows please help me...........

Comment: Please refactor your question in order to make it readable. Fix indentation and try to put some punctuation.

Comment: please make a question clearly

Comment: Before your for loop declare a string array `String[] dataStrings = new String[finalResultLength];` then as the last line of your for loop add `dataStrings[i]=result;`

Comment: i already tried this exact code, but it shows null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this way as well.

Create an ArrayList of size 'finalresultlengt' and the add the values in.

```
 list.add(result);  // variable 'result' in your case is the value from JSON
```

If you have more values to be added, create a POJO class.

```
class POJO {
    private String dataVal;

    public void setDataVal(String dataVal) {
        this.dataVal = dataVal;
    }

    public String getDataVal() {
        return dataVal;
     }
 }
```

Then create an ArrayList of type POJO.

```
 ArrayList<POJO> list = new ArrayList<POJO>(finalresultlengt);
```

EDIT

```
JSONArray  finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
int finalresultlengt=finalResult.length();
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(finalresultlengt);

for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length(); i++) {
      json_data = finalResult.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println("json dataa"+json_data.names().toString());
      JSONObject menuObject = json_data.getJSONObject("Response");
      result=   menuObject.getString("data");
      list.add(result);   
 }
```

Populate values from ArrayList.

```
 for(String value : list) 
      System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: can you please show an example for arraylist, i want to add only few data

Comment: Hi Renjith i use                                                      for(String value : list) 
      System.out.println(value); for printing, but it print only the 3 rd element and i print the size of list it shows 1 why?????????

Comment: check the value of finalresultlengt

Comment: can you please give me a solution to my problemmmm

Comment: try printing the list size each time you add! Check for any unusual behaviour

Comment: all the time it shows System.out.println(  list.size()); as 1

Comment: Make sure you instantiate ArrayList OUTSIDE loops!

Comment: I use the same code as you given...but it doesn't work properly